# Defining console port in ARM kernel image

Tags: kernel, u-boot, serial-console

I have an ARM Dev board using an RK3566 CPU that I'm building a kernel for.

I would like to control the board using the UART connector. This works during U-Boot process, but my issue is that when I build the kernel, it automatically switches to trying to use `ttyS2`, which has no data on it, and therefore the kernel hangs.

How can I define which port the kernel should use for the console? Or how do I append console setting from U-Boot?

- I do already have a working kernel embedded on my board, but I need to have the possibility of booting my own kernel and OS.

  The original kernel uses the command: `console=ttyFIQ0`. The original kernel also loads `ttyS1` at `irq=54` and `ttyS7` at `irq=55` (I assume `ttyS7` is the one for the OS, since the original os sits on partition 7?)
- I was able to avoid my original error of `ttyS2` failed to request DMA, by changing the `extlinux.conf` file to the `ttyFIQ0` port, but my issue remains now that it still tries to use `ttyS2`, but hangs at

  ```
  fe660000.serial: ttyS2 at MMIO 0xfe660000 (irq = 30, base_baud = 1500000) is a 16550A
  ```

Comment: The `U-Boot` has the serial port compiled in, while the kernel uses the port defined in the command line or in the device tree. How do you build your system (Yocto? Buildroot? From scratch?)? Check the `console=` item of your command line. You can also check it in the `U-Boot` prompt using `printenv` and change it with `setenv`, but the actual variable changes with implementation.

Comment: Thank you @Philippos, I was just now able to append a new serial port using the extlinux.conf file. I'm going to make an edit / update now of my original question as now it's somewhat changed slightly. I'm buiding my kernel based on dieselnutjob rk3566 kernel found on GitHub and GCC. I'm quite new to this so I don't know if it answers your question on how I'm building the kernel

Comment: So now you get have a serial console on UART0, where you get the boot messages from the kernel (I assume you use a serial cable to watch it with a terminal app on another computer)? And that ttyS2 line is the last you see there? This doesn't look like an error, so it could be the next step where the boot hangs. `extlinux.conf`? So this is some `syslinux` system?

Comment: @Philippos, I think you are right, yes. I was able to solve my issues though by using the correct dtb file, which defines the board configuration and which port the uart is sat on. Thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem by using the correct dtb file, as this has the correct port binding information in it, and making some changes to the extlinux.conf file

Comment: Can you share more about how you fixed it?